# Outlook Ignores Rule and Email goes to Junk

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, spam-prevention, rules

I've created a rule so that e-mails from `aaa@example.com` would go to `AAA` folder.

But anyhow sometimes one or two of these emails goes to Junk. What should I do in order to prevent these to go to Junk instead of `AAA` folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience with Outlook, I have found it will move messages to `Junk` if they seem suspicious (I am unsure how it determines this). Subsequently, your rule does not work on that message because it is not in the Inbox.

To fix this, select a message from the trusted user. Right click and point to `Junk` from the context menu. In the sub menu, choose `Never block sender`.

Now Outlook knows you trust this sender and it will not move any of the messages from that sender to `Junk` and the messages will stay in the Inbox where your rule can be applied to them.

More detail can be found here - [Overview of the Junk Email Filter](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-the-Junk-Email-Filter-5ae3ea8e-cf41-4fa0-b02a-3b96e21de089)

Comment: well I can't try if it is working or not, but thanks